# Can you blow a shofar for fun on Rosh Hashanah?

Tags: halacha, music, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

Last week, someone quoted a halacha in shul about blowing shofar on Rosh Hashanah if it's not for the mitzvah. He said that it's recommended not to, but if someone really wants to, they should blow for someone who hasn't heard it yet.

The Shulchan Aruch ([589:8](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.97)), however, talks about someone who is "playing" a shofar, and doesn't mention anything about doing so *b'dieved*. You're not *yotzei*, but it doesn't sound *assur*.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18961/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the Aruch HaShulchan and the Kitzur Yalkut Yosef **forbid adults to blow the Shofar  after one has fulfilled one's obligation**, with the exception of blowing for somebody else or if one isn't sure one fulfilled the mitzva.

[ערוך השולחן - אורח חיים סימן תקצו - מנהג התקיעות לאחר התפילה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01582.html#HtmpReportNum0505_L2)

> **ב** וכתב רבינו הרמ''א דלאחר שיצאו בזה – **אין לתקוע עוד בחנם**. אבל קטן, אפילו הגיעו לחינוך – מותר לומר לו שיתקע, ותוקע כל היום; עד כאן לשונו. ‏

[קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף סימן תקצו - תרועה גדולה בסוף התפלה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_28.html#HtmpReportNum0012_L2)

> **ב** אחר התפלה וסיום כל התקיעות כולל התרועה הגדולה, **אסור לתקוע שלא לצורך שום קול**, מאחר שכבר יצא ידי חובה, והתקיעה שבות ולא הותרה אלא לצורך מצוה. ורק אם היה ספק בתקיעות המצוה, אם עלו כהוגן או לאו, מותר לחזור ולתקוע לצאת מידי ספק. [שו''ת יביע אומר ח''ט חאו''ח סי' נב. ע''פ מ''ש הרא''ש (פ''ד דר''ה סי' יא) בשם הראב''ן. והעיטור דף קב]. ועל כל פנים אין למחות ביד הנוהגים להקל. [מאור ישראל ראש השנה כט:].‏
>
> **ג** מי שיש לו ספק ממש אם התקיעות היו כהלכה, או שקיצר בהם התוקע שלא כדין, חוזר לתקוע שלשים קול, לצאת מן הספק, אבל לא יברך, שספק ברכות להקל.‏
>
> **ד** קטן פחות מגיל בר מצוה, שהגיע לחינוך, מותר ליתן לו לתקוע ולהתלמד, ואין בזה איסור כלל. [ילקוט יוסף מועדים עמוד נח]. ‏

Comment: What about before fulfilling the obligation?

Comment: @Scimonster: From the SA you quote  (589:8), it seems to be OK. Nobody there queries why he's blowing for no good [halachic] reason. This seems counterintuitive. Then again, the Poskim I quote also only talk about afterwards, but ignore blowing for no good reason beforehand. Maybe "blowing beforehand" falls under the category of "practicing" - no matter what the actual reason you are blowing.

Comment: This is somewhat misleading about the Aruch Hashulchan (as he continues to bring an opposing view), and also, why not just bring the Rema himself?