# Can the toke'ah practice blowing on Erev Rosh Hashannah?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

For those that blow the shofar daily (except on Shabbat) throughout Ellul, common custom is not to blow on Erev Rosh Hashannah.

Does this regulation apply to **all** blowing, or only the one done *betzibbur* (in shul during Shacharit)? Thus, may the *toke'ah* practice shofar blowing on Erev Rosh Hashannah?

Comment: Note some stop blowing already today, three days before Rosh Hashana

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different reasons one doesn't blow on Erev Rosh Hashana, one to differentiate between Elul (where the sounding is a custom) and Rosh Hashana (where it is a *mitzva d'oraita*), another to "confuse the Satan".

The Magen Avraham is strict according to the second reason but R Yaakov Goldstein (on [OC 581:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.3?lang=en)) [cites](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/blowing-shofar-on-erev-rh/) a number of sources allowing it for practice

> It is forbidden to blow the Shofar, even for practice, in an open area. **One is however allowed to practice blowing the Shofar in a closed
>   room.** [This applies whether one is learning how to blow or is
>   trying to get used to blowing from a new Shofar. However one may
>   not blow the Shofar for no reason even in a closed room.]

and sources it

> The Magen Avraham writes that according to the reason that this custom is
>   done in order to confuse the Satan, then one may not blow at all. This
>   implies that one may not blow even for practice and even in a closed
>   room. **However from the Pnei Menachem and [Mishna Brura](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.3?lang=en&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.581.25&lang2=en) it implies that even
>   according to this reason in a closed room it is permitted to blow for
>   practice.**

see [there](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/blowing-shofar-on-erev-rh/) for detailed references and also [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2013/09/confusing-satan/)

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18961/759